# JSON Schema Validation having contraints value of one of them should be same as that of the other one

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Is it possible to validate the value of one field to be similar to that of another field while validating a payload schema?

If so how can we do it?

Example:

The email field value which we get in the following payload should have same value as that of login field:

```
Payload :
{
    "email":"robin.zen@gmail.com",
    "first_name":"Robin",
    "gender":1,
    "last_name":"Zen",
    "login":"robin.zen@gmail.com"
}
```

What should my JSON Schema look like to fulfill that requirement?

Comment: @greg-449 et al: The question is fairly straightforward, especially with some understanding of JSON Schema. Please suggest edits to the question instead.

Comment: @greg-449 Actually I am getting a payload with a following fields mentioned,I am applying JSON schema validation for required fields and data type.Is there any to validate the field value while applying JSON Schema Validation in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry you cannot do this using JSON Schema. You will have to do additional validation. You cannot test that one field is the same as another.

Comment: Yeah. At the moment, JSON Schema focuses on "structural validation", instead of data consistency. Data consistency would include things like "does one property equal another" or "is this a user ID that exists in the database?"
These validations should be performed in the application.